# Private communication between off-chain frontend app and hyper ledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to make a secure hyperledger fabric infrastructure to manage all nodes based on physical devices.
The front-end user application writes to HL. It asks for a random node and if it answers application sends request and payload.

What is the best way to guarantee private communication between off-chain frontend app and hyperledger?

I have already created private domain *secured by SSL certificate* for every node but this method doesn’t sound scalable - what if we have 10k nodes? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to communicate directly with the Peer, the endpoint's already able to be secured with TLS.

However, under an ideal situation, your web app, would communicate with your back-end server (lets say NodeJS Express server). Your Express server would be TLS secured and your web app would communicate via https. Your Express server would then use the Fabric Node SDK to communicate with your network, which is also TLS secured communication. You're not configuring anything more extensively than you would have while building a TLS-secured web server in the first place.

To your last point, who owns the 10k nodes? An organization would only be expected to own a few nodes, and your few nodes would be handling your transactions, you wouldn't be submitting to other organizations peers. You owning so many peer's in a network would defeat the purpose of Fabric's consensus, allowing you to compromise the network by always being able to provide policy quorum.